# Which tools exists for byte-level inspection of files?

Tags: ms-word, binary, binaryfiles, file-recovery

I have a partially corrupted MS-Word file which I'd like to inspect in the byte-level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[HexEdit](http://www.physics.ohio-state.edu/~prewett/hexedit/) is pretty nice (allows you to edit files too)

Answer (score 2):

I like the freeware hex editor [xvi32](http://www.chmaas.handshake.de/delphi/freeware/xvi32/xvi32.htm) for this kind of task.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a hex editor. Some text editors can run in this mode. I always used [PSPad](http://pspad.com)for this

Answer (score 2):

As always there's emacs, [hexl-mode](http://www.phys.ufl.edu/docs/emacs/emacs_422.html) allows you to view and edit hex-files.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are many, but [Ultraedit](http://www.ultraedit.com/) does this.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Visual Studio installed, you can add the .dat extension to the file and open it in Visual Studio to get a hex/ASCII display.

Answer (score 0):

[010 Editor](http://www.sweetscape.com/010editor/) is nice for looking at files that follow some template, it'll try to turn the raw data into meaningful labeled values for you.

Answer (score 0):

Take a gander at [BeyondCompare](http://www.scootersoftware.com) for file comparisons; version 3 has comparisons for Word files as well. You'd be surprised at how often you'll use it once you have it.